# Is there a way to compile the same source file in two distinct languages in one CMake run?

Tags: cmake

I know the title may sound bizarre, but please, read on.

I develop a C++ software that is based on the header library that can be compiled to run on both x64 and CUDA.

In recent years the proper way to build a source file in CUDA is to use the special CMake language, `CUDA`, so if I want to compile an executable on CUDA I simply set the language like this:

```
set_property(SOURCE test.cpp PROPERTY LANGUAGE CUDA)
```

I have unit tests based on `test.cpp` which subsequently can be compiled on either x64 on CUDA as well.

So far to build the tests I launch CMake twice - once to build the x64 version and another (with different flag) to build the CUDA version.

The question: is there any chance to build *both* versions of my test (i.e. x64 and CUDA) that is based on the same source files in one CMake run? I know I force one CMake to spawn other CMakes in superbuild-like fashion, but this is not what I ask.

Comment: I assume not: With cmake you write one build description to build for multiple platforms. This the runs for the platforms are independent.

Comment: You may build the same source file as many times as you want. Just assign unique **target name** for the executable created. But for assign different properties for the single source file for different targets, you probably need to create those targets in the different directories. So `set_property(SOURCE test.cpp PROPERTY LANGUAGE CUDA)` would be applied only for the target, created in the current directory.